# How to find JSON tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "global_view": {
        "circle_el": {
            "simple_view": {
                "name": "My Name One"
            }
        }            
        "circle_el": {
            "simple_view": {
                "name": "My Name Two"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this jquery function:

```
    jsonCall_data("data/data.json");

    function jsonCall_data(data_source) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: data_source,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find(JSON.global_view).each(function(){
                    $(this).find(JSON.circle_el).each(function(){
                        var el_name = $(this).find(JSON.name);
                        content_container.append(
                            '<li id="'+ el_name +'"></li>'
                        )
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

my question is how to get each `global_el` to create a list with some class/id, like this:

```
<li id="My Name One"></li> // first circle el
<li id="My Name Two"></li> // second circl el
```

much thx for help, i hope that is clear.

Comment: You have duplicated keys. I'd suggest you fix that before going any further...

Comment: Your JSON will not work as you expect due to the duplicate keys

Comment: Yes, it appears as if `global_view` should reference an array `global_view:[{"circle":"something"},{"circle":"somethingelse"}]`

Comment: ok but how can i find some tag inside of some key?

Comment: I believe jQuery won't help you there, you need recursive iteration to "find" a key. Though, if the structure is as simple as posted, once you put the circle objects into an array, a `for` loop would be enough.